# using webrequest to issue a rename command that moves FTP folders

Tags: c#, webrequest

[How can I use FTP to move files between directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4864925/355974)

I were trying to use the webrequest object to move a folder, say

move `data/current`

to `data/previous/1/`

however when i try to do it simply by setting source folder as source, target folder as destination, i have got the exception

> The request URI is invalid for this FTP command.

should i not be doing that at all? how should i achieve this objective neatly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that I get this error when the request URI has a trailing slash (even if it is a directory). Try removing the last slash on `data/previous/1/`.