# How to move file within FTP

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I am having some files in FTP having a directory named say "ParentDirectory" and it too have a  child folder named "Child1". How can I move a file from ParentDirectory to its child folder.

Say ParentDirectory is having file named "File01.pdf" in it, now I want to move it to
    ParentDirectory/Child1/

Without downloading a file then again uploading it to server and then deleting it from ftp server. Is there any way to directly move the file to its child directory.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use FTP to move files between directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864925/how-can-i-use-ftp-to-move-files-between-directories)

Comment: @Petoj can you please give it in answer section such that I can mark it as answered. As following the link I got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link served by @Petoj helped to get the solution.

It was being provided as comment to the question. As it was not in the answer section I could not mark it as being answered.

possible duplicate of How can I use FTP to move files between directories? – Petoj Nov 30 '11 at 9:23

Answer (score 0):

Would it be an Option for you to programm kind of small Client Server App which [moves / deletes Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx) on your FTP host by getting some signals from the client?

There might be an issue with files which are in use from the FTP-Server but you can check this programmatically.

Comment: We programmatically prepare Web Request and URI, deletefile, downloadfile, getting list of files and in there now I want to add up  functionalities to upload and move file.

Answer (score -2):

Using your favorite FTP GUI client simply connect to the remote server and drag and drop your file from the parent directory to the child directory.

Comment: I think OP wants to do that programmatically, don't he?

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com I need them in code and not using any GUI client such as FileZilla

Comment: Sorry did not notice the c# tag just the FTP tag