# Move files from source FTP to destination FTP with different credentials for source and destination

Tags: ftp, ftpwebrequest

I'm working on a scenario wherein I need to move some files from one FTP location to another. The FTP server is the same but credentials for the source and destination are different.

For example,

I need to copy files

FROM

"ftp://sampleftp.com/sourceFolder" with login credentials **"User1", "Password1"**

TO

"ftp://sampleftp.com/destinationFolder" with login credentials **"user2","password_2"**

Kindly note the different credentials I have used above for source and destination.

I referred to [this similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4865062/2377928) link but that seems to work for the FTP folder with constant login credentials.

Can someone please guide me on how best can I implement this?

Comment: My (unproven) suspicion is that unless you want to try to use ftp commands to grant access from one account to the other, you may have to download and re-upload the data.  If this is a commercial provider, it's not actually a given that both are actually present on the same server instance, even though they are reached in the same way.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was also thinking. But just wondering if there was any direct way to move those files which would be much better in terms of performance

Comment: Can you get ssh access to a shell session?  That would make exploring options a lot easier.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Exploring the FTP drive? Is that what you mean? I'm using WinSCP for now. I'm kinda new to using FTP so i'm not really aware of connecting with shell