# Move a file to another Ftp directory and rename it

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, rename, file-move

I've been struggling with that for the past few hours and I literally can't find a way to do it without downloading and uploading the file again. Is it even possible?

This question is kind of a copy of this one: [How can I use FTP to move files between directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864925/how-can-i-use-ftp-to-move-files-between-directories)  but I have the feeling that its not solved, although it's answered.

Renaming the file itself is quite easy and works without any problems, but how do I move it to another directory?

I have this sample code:

```
string uri2 = "ftp://ftpUser@testFtp.com/mainFolder/moveFrom/file.txt";

f = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uri2));

f.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPass);
f.KeepAlive = false;
f.UsePassive = true;
f.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
f.Timeout = 5000;
f.UseBinary = true;

f.RenameTo = "ftp://ftpUser@testFtp.com/mainFolder/moveTo/file.txt";

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)f.GetResponse();

response.Close();
f.Abort();
```

I get the same error as in the other topic:

`The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).`

Using a relative path, doesn't do anything different.

Do I do something wrong or is the only way to download from the source folder, upload to dest and then delete the file from the source?
That's 3 calls to the FTP server..

Comment: And you're sure the file path is correct, ie. the file is actually there?

Comment: Yes, the file is there and I can open it in the browser.

Comment: What relative path did you try to use? Did you try `/mainfolder/moveFrom/file.txt` and `/mainfolder/moveTo/file.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET puts an abstraction layer over the FTP protocol  which can abstract too much away and thus makes some things impossible or tricky. I did not have a source code of .NET, but based on the [source of FTPWebRequest from Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/FtpWebRequest.cs) (an implementation which tries to be compatible with .NET) it will do for any operations on URIs:

- Split first the URI into a directory part and a `file_name` part (see `CWDAndSetFileName` in source).
- CWD to the directory.
- And do the operation there.

With renaming `URL=ftp:/host/foo/bar/file1` to `RenameTo=file2`  this means in FTP commands:

```
... log into host ...
CWD foo/bar
RNFR file1
RNTO file2
```

But, if you have source and target in different directories, e.g. `RenameTo=/foo/bar2/file2`, you would rather have it like this:

```
... log into host ...
RNFR foo/bar/file1
RNTO foo/bar2/file2
```

But unfortunately that is not the way it is implemented :(

If you are lucky you could try to use a relative path, e.g. `RenameTo=../bar2/file2`, which should result in

```
... log into host ...
CWD foo/bar
RNFR file1
RNTO ../bar2/file2
```

This should probably work with the Mono-Implementation, but I don't know if it also works with real .NET.

Edit:
I just had a look at the [source for .NET 4.5](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_FtpControlStream.cs). It differs from Mono in that it does not do a CWD to the basedir before the file operation, but instead prepends the current basedir to the name if the name is relative. Thus with `renameTo=../bar2/file2` this results in

```
 RNFR foo/bar/file1
 RNTO foo/bar/../bar2/file2
```

while with an absolute name `renameTo=/bar2/file2` this would result in

```
 RNFR foo/bar/file1
 RNTO /bar2/file2
```

Depending on type and setup of the FTP server the absolute name might get interpreted as relative to the root of the users home directory, or it might be a real absolute path. So it would be best to work only with relative path and the solution with `../dir/` should work with Mono and "real" .NET.

Comment: I just tested the relative path suggestion from @steffen on .NET 4.0, and it worked. It resulted in the following communication  with the FTP server (Sniffed with Wireshark): 
[RNFR pub/test1/testfile.txt]
[350 File exists, ready for destination name]
[RNTO pub/test1/../test2/testfile3.txt]
[250 RNTO command successful.]

So the file was moved AND renamed.

Comment: @Steffen Thank you for the detailed answer! I will look into it and  get back to you. Do you have sample code?

Comment: @Apostrofix:  No, I don't write C# myself, I only can read it and I know the FTP protocol. But it should probably just be `f.RenameTo="../moveTo/file.txt"` in your example.