# Move file to parent folder on FTP

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm trying to move files from a folder into it's parent folder.

I had issues moving files before, something to do with absolute versus relative path on the `RenameTo` property. I'm currently getting a 553 error(file name not allowed).

Files are in "//blah/John/Update/Done/" and I'd like to move to "//../Update/".

Here is a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
string ftpConn="ftp://blah/John/Update/";
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++ )
{
    var requestMove = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpConn + "Done/" + fileList[i].fName);
    requestMove.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
    requestMove.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPass);                   
    requestMove.RenameTo = ".../John/Update/" + fileList[i].fName;
    requestMove.GetResponse();
}
```

I've tried changing the `RenameTo` property to the absolute path and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by `...`. Try `"./../" + fileList[i].fName` which expands to `"/blah/John/Update/" + fileList[i].fName` if the current directory is `/blah/John/Update/Done`

Comment: @cubrr That worked! Would you like to put that as an answer to get credit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `...` is valid in relative paths.
You probably meant:

```cs
requestMove.RenameTo = "./../" + fileList[i].fName;
//                      ^  ^
//        Current dir ──┘  │
//                         │
//      Go up one folder ──┘
```

If your current working directory is `/blah/John/Update/Done/`, `./../` effectively represents `/blah/John/Update`.

More about relative path syntax [here](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/com/Gp_ToolRef/sharing_tools_and_toolboxes/pathnames_explained_colon_absolute_relative_unc_and_url.htm).

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Don't be afraid to ask if you have further questions.