# How to move FTP files to SubDirectory in c#?

Tags: c#

How to move files from FTP folder to another sub directory folder.

**E.g:**

My FTP file path from `"ftp://3.111.123.001/ftproot/Incoming/Test.xml"`

I would like to move `"ftp://3.111.123.001/ftproot/Incoming/Test.xml"` file to below path:
`"ftp://3.111.123.001/ftproot/Incoming/Processed/Test.xml"`

How to do. Please help me to solve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use FTP to move files between directories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864925/how-can-i-use-ftp-to-move-files-between-directories)

Comment: Uri serverFile = new Uri("ftp://3.211.211.001/ftproot/Incomming/ProcessedFiles/ITEM_2016-06-13T02_06_34.200-04_00.xml");
            FtpWebRequest reqFTP= (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(serverFile);
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ftpuser", "test");
            reqFTP.RenameTo = "ftp://3.211.211.001/ftproot/Incomming/ProcessedFiles/Test";
            
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();

Comment: I am getting below error:

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).